# How to make API call in JMeter after specific time has passed

Tags: time, jmeter

I am having the following situation in JMeter script:

1. User gets ACCESS Token and logs in
2. 50 GET APIs in system.
3. 50 Threads.
4. Loop is set to FOREVER.
5. Duration is set to 10800 seconds (3 hours)
6. Login method where User gets the token is placed inside *Once Only Controller* so that Login is executed just once per thread.
7. User times out in 60min and gets logged out automatically.
8. There exists a Refresh token method which gets a new ACCESS token.

I need to perform stress testing using JMeter using 50 threads and run it for 3 hours. The thing is if 50 threads are running, they will start getting time out after 60min.

Now if I place the Refresh Token method to get a new ACCESS token after the 50 API calls, then is there a way where I call this method when it is close to 60 min of execution, for eg: Refresh token method is called after every 55min?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to work on your scenario. I am sharing - What I have done after understanding your scenario.

In the below screenshot, you can see 2 threads which have 1 authentication request started via Only Once Controller. After some time, again authentication request is sent.

[image]
Approach:-

1. Set a user defined variable as shown below:-

[image]
2. Then use the JSR223 Post Processor under a request to execute the below code.

```
def start_Time = vars.get("startTime")
log.info "start_Time>>>>>>>"+start_Time

long currentTime = ${__time(,)}
log.info "currentTime>>>>>>>"+currentTime;

long diff=currentTime.toLong()-start_Time.toLong();
log.info "diff>>>>>>>"+diff

if(diff>=2000){
    start_Time = ${__time(,)};
    vars.put("startTime",start_Time.toString());
}
vars.put("flag",diff.toString());
log.info "FlagValue>>>>>>>"+vars.get("flag")
```

[image]
3. Below is if condition used for the authentication request.

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: @ZeeKay If it helped you can also vote. Please check, "https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers" for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue and this was the solution I applied:

1. Add another Thread group that will run parallelly
   [image]
2. In the Thread Group - Main, get the completion status of the Thread Group and set it to a Property
   [image]
3. In the Thread Group - Authentication include a While Controller to loop until your Thread Group Main completes
4. Add the Authentication request along with the Constant delay inside
5. Get the Token and set it to a Property value
6. Refer that Property in the Thread Group - Main Requests

[image]